# sp_xml_preparedocument error handling, what does it mean: SELECT @err = @@error + coalesce(@err, 4711)

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

[Here](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/travisl/archive/2005/01/04/3931.aspx#3222) (and not only there) people are using the following code to handle an error from sp_xml_preparedocument

```
EXEC @err = sp_xml_preparedocument @hdoc OUTPUT, @xmlDoc
SELECT @err = @@error + coalesce(@err, 4711)
```

Are there any reasons for this? And what does 4711 mean in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little late but...

"4711" is just a number that is quite often used by German developers when they need some error code. I've seen this in literally every code I ran into over the past 15 years.

It actually is a reference to a perfume that was quite popular in Germany during the 70s/80s. The label on the perfume bottle has a big "4711" sign on it.

[image]

Comment: That is fun! Could you provide some proof of 4711 being a popular error code from German developers?

Comment: @Mike https://www.google.de/#q=filetype:cpp+4711 or https://www.google.de/#q=filetype:java+4711 show various examples. Not always used as an error code but whenever a random integer is needed. :)

Comment: Actually, google search results are not very convincing. In cpp file type I see 4711 has just slightly more hits than 4710 or 4712. For java 4711 is less popular than 4710 or 4712.

Answer (score 1):

4711 doesnt make any sense. I think its just a random number copy pasted from previous code. You can return any non-zero according to this -> [Error handling](http://www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-II.html)

```
SELECT * FROM sys.messages WHERE language_id = 1033 and message_id = 4711
```